# Virtual Box giving error after ubuntu update

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed windows 7 using virtual box. After Ubuntu update, when I try to power on windows 7, the following error message comes:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows 7 x64.

The virtual machine 'Windows 7 x64' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

I have tried the following and its still not working

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

It shows a dependency error when installing virtualbox-dkms

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-dkms : Depends: virtualbox (>= 4.3.10-dfsg-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue after ubuntu 14.04 update, this is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms

sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem as you with a recent Ubuntu update.  Updating VirtualBox to 4.3.20 worked for me.  Download the deb file for Ubuntu 14.04 here:

```
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
```

Then uninstall VirtualBox 4.3.18 and install new version:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox

sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.3_4.3.20-96996~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb
```

Replace amd64 with i386 if you're running a 32 bit system.  Hope this helps.